# Why I don’t get any votes when I have answered correctly?

Tags: discussion, support

The reason I’m asking this, is because yesterday, someone in **Islam S.E.** asked wether Quran mentions that werewolves and vampires and aliens exist, and I answered correctly each one of them.

I want to know if my answers are correct?:

1. [**Does Quran indicates that aliens, werewolves and vampires exist?**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/50256/23833)
2. [**Digital art and drawing cartoons is prohibited in Islam?**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/45765/23833)
3. https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/46407/23833

I want to know, what’s the main reason that I didn’t get any vote for these answers that I listed. I have answered correctly, so what’s wrong? Or, have I answered correctly? Or wrong?

Just in curiosity.

Comment: Are you answering for the sake of getting votes?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Oh no, I just want to know why because I’m trying only to get rid of ban message so that I can ask again, that’s all.

Comment: As far as I can see you actually have no ban at least on ISE.

Comment: @Medi1Saif then why it doesn’t allow me to ask any question?

Comment: Ups my fault ISE-Meta not the main site!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Is it ok if I do want to get up votes half for the sake of earning reputations and half for the sake of God? Because, what I’m trying to do is, to get the same up votes just like Community Wiki gets. Because it makes you feel great and popular as far as I know.

Comment: Community wikis are usually user posts that have been considered as good and the user himself considered leaving it for the community, so it gets out of his "ownership". From a Muslim perspective it shouldn't bother you if others praise you but it should make you worry, as it might awaken the self-pride inside your nafs.

Comment: Actually my advise for you is: consider specifying on a topic and answering questions on that topic in a good manner. Try to read a lot on the topic, in the sources, not only copying from fatwa sites or blogs or other threads. You actually have a question ban not an answer ban make the best of it.